# How to change the Y scale for my plot graph in matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
with open('data/covid.csv', encoding="utf8") as file_obj:
    file_data = csv.DictReader(file_obj, skipinitialspace = True)
    #storing info of dose 1 in dictionary
    dicti = {}
    for row in file_data:
        key = row['State/UTs']
        if key in dicti:
            dicti[key] = row['Dose 1']
        else:
            key = row['State/UTs']
            dicti[key] = row['Dose 1']
    
    print(dicti)
    valuesL = list(dicti.values())
    for i in range(0, len(valuesL)):
        valuesL[i] = int(valuesL[i])
    plt.figure(figsize=(18,12))
    ax = plt.bar(list(dicti.keys()),valuesL, color = "green")
    
    plt.xlabel("State/uts", fontsize = 30)
    plt.ylabel("Number of people who have taken dose 1", fontsize = 30)
    plt.title('States VS people who have taken dose 1', fontsize = 30)
    plt.xticks(rotation=80)
    for patch in ax.patches:
        width = patch.get_width()
        height = patch.get_height()
        x = patch.get_x()
        y = patch.get_y()
    
        plt.text(x , y + height + 4, '{}'.format(height))
    
    plt.show()
```

this is my code the graph shows the y axis to be ranging from 0.5 to 1, I want it to change according to the values of dictionary that range from 10000 to 10000000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your looking for [set_ylim](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim.html).

```
bottom = 10000
top = 10000000
ax.set_ylim(bottom, top)
```

or

```
plt.ylim(bottom, top)
```

Comment: it says bar container object has no attribute set_ylim